# Finding best route in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, routing, route

I've already tried snapping to the network, tried switching end points to any vertex and still don't work. I have even created single layer of my all routes, and then created network layer and still error occurs. Please help me.

On the straight route it works

[image]

but when I try to select after the turn it won't work.

[image]

---

Warning text:

> Warning: No route from location "Location 1" to location "Location 2".
>   Error: No solution found.

Location 1 and Location 2 are replaced with addresses in my province.

My goal is to highlight a route from point to point (like from the border of my province to the harbour; it's a point feature but it isn't shown on screens) and every time when i want to highlight a route, and turn occurs the error appears.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please **[edit]** your question to include the error message as text (it's very hard to read on your image), and details about what exactly you are trying to do and what about it doesn't work.  Please include the steps you have followed.

Comment: Looks like you need to set up a 'cost' http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-2-creating-a-multimodal-network-dataset.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3DC587EF952B4BA581EF89F2CF1DAD64

Comment: @Mapperz can I ask you what do you mean by a 'cost'? We didn't use network analyst on our activites during my studies and my promoter told me to use it. I just created that road layers and then network layer from them. I' ve read already all GIS tutorials.

Comment: you need the 'network analysis' extension with arcgis which is extra then you need to build your network with resistance (like max mph/kph) etc.

Comment: @Mapperz Well i have it, I' ve already created network but i don' t have any informations about the routes that i've used to build network dataset (obly information that i have is it's length). I just want to highlight a route from first point to the other second. Thats all. And thank you for trying to help.

Comment: What were the precise steps (all tools and parameter values) that you used to create your network dataset?  Then what were the precise steps that you used to try and find the route, and then highlight it?

Comment: @PolyGeo First i've created my all my route layers. Then I've created network dataset using all that route layers just clicking next in the process of making it. Then thing that you see above occured so I've tried something else. I've meade a layer where all routes are on it (not like before couple layers with routes), created network dataset from this layer and same error occured.

Comment: For a Network Analyst question I suspect that you will struggle to attract a potential answerer without revising your question to included a lot more detail.